# flutter/dart : How to close camera after continuous few barcodes scanning

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used **flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0** package to scan barcodes it work fine but I scan continuously and after few barcodes i want to close the camera and return back to screen now I am stock so how the camera is closed after scanning few barcodes.
the following is a scenario I wont to implement

```
 scanBarcode() {
                  FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver(
                    "#ff6666",
                    "Cancel",
                    false,
                    ScanMode.DEFAULT,
                  )!
                      .listen(
                    (barcode) {
                      setState(() {
                        list.add(barcode);
                      });

                      if (list.length == 10) {
                        // I want to close camera here and show page again?
                      }
                    },
                  );
                }
```

Comment: can't you just pop? or push the desired page?

Comment: I have tried pop but it is not working when the condition meets only the screen is switched to black blank screen nothings are appeared

Comment: the issue is that what you want to do, currently is not supported in the package. Check out [this similar issue on github](https://github.com/AmolGangadhare/flutter_barcode_scanner/issues/30#issue-484326334) and the [author's response](https://github.com/AmolGangadhare/flutter_barcode_scanner/issues/113#issuecomment-826172623)

Comment: this package only calls the native (Android/iOS) implementation using event channels. You can however implement is yourself. This means you have to dig into kotlin and swift code. Or you can try finding other package.

Comment: @Zoltán thanks a lot for your comments. do you know about barcode scanning package which fulfill my requirements? if know plz mention.

Comment: Unfortunately i haven't used other scanners, but have a look at [these packages](https://fluttergems.dev/qr-code-bar-code/) and search them on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) to see their usage. Maybe you'll find one that suits you.

Comment: i had the same issue, check my answer this works well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The workaround **is to loop on single scan**. So as a result you can still continue to use `flutter_barcode_scanner` package :).

In my case i don't need to call setState or something like to update the UI but you can do it if you need.

```
  Future<String?> _scanBarcodeNormal() async {
    String? barcodeScanRes;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode('#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
    return barcodeScanRes;
  }

void _scanBarCodeListAndFetchData() async{
    String? barcode = await _scanBarcodeNormal();
    final List<String> barcodeList = [];
    // continue scanning
    while(barcode != null){
      if(barcode == "-1"){ // cancel button -> -1
          barcode = null;
      }
      // add the barcode
      else {
        // avoid duplicates
        if(!barcodeList.contains(barcode)){
          barcodeList.add(barcode);
        }
        // you can also call setState(() {....} here
        if (barcodeList.length == 10) {
            barcode = null; // out !
        }
        else{ // next scan
            barcode = await _scanBarcodeNormal();
        }
      }
    }

    if(barcodeList.isEmpty) {
      UiUtils.showToast(message: "No barcode scanned, abort", toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    else{
      UiUtils.showToast(message: "${barcodeList.length} barcodes scanned", toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      // your work
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable help. This is what I wanted to implement.